# Indonesian applying for Schengen Visa in Hong Kong

Tags: visas, passports, hong-kong, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesian working in Macau and am planning to go to Italy-UK-France.
Because Macau doesn't have an Italian or a UK Embassy, I have to apply for Schengen and UK visas in Hong Kong.

How do I apply for the visas when I need my original passport to go back to Macau to work?

Comment: Are you a permanent resident of Macau? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passport of original country, Macao Permanent Resident can enter HK with Macao SAR Permanent Resident Identity Card and [Visit Permit for Residents of Macao SAR to Hong Kong SAR](http://www.dsi.gov.mo/hktravelpermit_e.jsp) for <30days.

The Visit Permit is valid for 7 years and holder can visit the HK on multiple occasions. Applicant should make the application in person in the [Identification Services Bureau office](http://www.dsi.gov.mo/location_e.html). Applicants have to submit 1 passport photo and Macau ID card for verification. The permit cosst 100MOP and takes 5 working days.

PS1: Macauese cannot enter HK with Macau passport.

PS2: The permit is independence to the 7 days transit visa free policy in HK.